# How to save the detected object into a new image

Tags: python, opencv, cascade, drawrectangle

I'm new in `OpenCV`. I'm trying to save the detected object into a new image.

What should I do?

This is the code I copied from a tutorial:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
tric_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')

img = cv2.imread('anthon18c.png')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

tric = tric_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.01,7)
for (x,y,w,h) in tric:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to correctly format it.

Comment: don't put question in title. Question should be in body.

Comment: if you found code in tutorial then maybe you can find in the same tutorial how to save it. Or find documentation for `cv2` in python. It uses `imread`, `imshow`, so it can be something like `im...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save image named *img*, you can use:

```
cv2.imwrite('/path/to/destination/image.png', img)
```